# TodoTasks from MS Graph Java SDK have attachment field set to null, even that 'hasAttachments' field is true

Tags: java, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using MS Graph Java SDK (version 5.41.0). I'm trying to get some ToDo tasks from specific list as follows:

```
_userClient
            .users(USER_INFO)
            .todo()
            .lists("SomeExampleListIdThatWorks")
            .tasks()
            .buildRequest()
            .get();
```

And I would like to check if there are any attachment by checking if they exist:

```
tasksPage.getCurrentPage().filter(e->e.hasAttachments).forEach(e->{
            List<AttachmentBase> list = e.attachments.getCurrentPage();
        });
```

But line 2 is throwing NPE because `e.attachments` is null.

I know that I have attachments because I've added them with native app (they are email links, if that matters).

Question is why `e.attachments` is null, even is `e.hasAttachments` is true?

Comment: To get the attachments for the Todo list , you can also check:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/taskfileattachment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=java

Comment: @MehtabSiddique Thanks for hint, but I would like to get all ID's of the selected task, and in example you have sent, I can see that I can get specific attachment

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because `attachments` is a relationship and you need to expand them.

```
_userClient
        .users(USER_INFO)
        .todo()
        .lists("SomeExampleListIdThatWorks")
        .tasks()
        .buildRequest()
        .expand("attachments") 
        .get();
```

Comment: Thanks for hit but it's not working for me :(. BTW you cannot do like you showed, but instead:
        _userClient
            .users("exampleuser")
            .todo()
            .lists("listId")
            .tasks("taskId")
            .buildRequest()
            .expand("attachments")
            .get();

Comment: @PastorPL Thank, make more sense to add expand to the first method chain